# c++ vector insert unexpected behaivor

Tags: c++, vector, insert

Please explain why the following code works as expected (the element is added at the 2nd position):

```
std::vector<int> v(5);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    v[i] = i;

std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin()+1;
it = v.insert(it, 33);

cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << " " << v[3] << " " << v[4] << endl;
//outs: 0 33 1 2 3
```

and the following doesn't (the element is added at first position):

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(5);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    v[i] = i;

std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin()+1;
it = v.insert(it, 33);

cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << " " << v[3] << " " << v[4] << endl;
//outs: 33 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Surely you meant `resize()` instead of `reserve()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> v(5);
```

Creates a 5 element vector

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(5);
```

Creates an empty vector, but allocates room to push back 5 elements later

so trying to access `v[i]` is undefined behaviour, since the vector doesn't actually contain any elements at this point.

Your second example could be changed to:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.resize(5);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    v[i] = i;
```

This properly creates a 5 element vector (you could use this when you don't initially know the size at the time you allocate the vector)

or

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(5);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    v.push_back(i);
```

Which reserves space for 5 elements, which get inserted in order (this would be commonly used when you know beforehand how many elements you have, but each element doesn't need to know what index it is to be inserted at - each one just gets added to the end of the vector.

Note, in either case, you can still add additional items - the vector will just get resized.  To keep your code optimal, the aim is to try and keep to a minimum the number of times your vector does get resized.

Comment: `std::vector<int> v(5);` performs automatic `v.resize(5);`, correct? is there any way to add elements, other than push_back?

Comment: Yeah, the constructor version resizes the `vector` at the start.  There are multiple ways to add items to a `vector` - you've included two of them in your original post - the `[]` operator will let you re-assign an element in the `vector`.  `insert` lets you add a new item in the middle, and `push_back` lets you add one at the end.  Other containers, such as `deque` also have `push_front`

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add elements to a vector i used `reserve(n);` other than push_back, because push_back is slow.

Comment: Does push_back speed up after a reserve? How slow is it?

Comment: @SkyRipper: If you've used `reserve()` to set sufficient `capacity()` then `push_back()` just constructs new elements in the reserved space (without reallocating the entire vector).

Comment: @benjymous: don't forget resize(N,elem); as another way to add elements.

Comment: @doctorlove the issue is, that if your `vector` is full, the library will reallocate a new bigger buffer, and copy the data over.  Obviously this will slow things down, so it's better to be able to only do your buffer allocation once.  Typically, `vector` will allocate a bit more than you need each time it resizes itself to give you some breathing room (e.g. a full 10 element may get resized to 15 elements when you `push_back`)

Comment: @benjymous I know. That's why I specifically asked what happened if you reserved space first - and I meant enough space. Clearly reserving less space than you know you need would leave the same problem. Sorry for not being clear ;-)

Answer (score 6):

It is undefined behaviour. `std::vector::reserve` does not resize the vector, so calling `v[i]` is an out of bounds access.

You need to either call `v.resize(5)` to expand the vector to hold 5 elements, or call `v.push_back` inside the loop.